# jqGrid - Setting database record nested property as row id

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

In my grid, I configured jsonReader "id" property to get my database record as row id. 
Like this:

**JSON**:

```
{
    id: 1,
    price: 99.99,
    data: {
        dataId: 2
    }
}
```

**JSON READER**

```
 ...
 jsonReader: {
     root: 'list',
     total: 'count',
     id: 'id' 
 },
 ...
```

What if I want to set "dataId" as the row id? I tried to define it by using dot notation in a string, but it doesn't work. Here's my grid options:

```
var gridOptions = {
    height: 250,                
    colNames: ['Nome', 'Preço'],
    colModel: [{
        name:'ipvodAsset.title',
        index:'ipvodAsset.title', 
        width: 200, 
        sorttype:'string', 
        searchoptions: { sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc'] }
    }, {
        name:'price',
        index:'price', 
        width:200, 
        sorttype:'currency', 
        formatter: 'currency',
        searchoptions: { sopt:['eq','ne','gt','ge','bw','bn','cn','nc'] }
    }],
    jsonReader: { id: 'data.data.id' },
    prmNames: {'order': 'order'},
    gridView: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    sortname: 'title',
    viewrecords : true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    altRows: true,
    dataType="local",
    data = [
        { "id": 1, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 2 } },
        { "id": 2, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 3 } },
        { "id": 3, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 4 } },
        { "id": 4, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 5 } }
    ]
};
```

Comment: jqGrid can be used to display array of items of data in a grid. Is "JSON" what you posted is an item of data and you have columns like `id` and `price` and want to use `data.dataId` as the rowid? You included `root: 'list'` in `jsonReader` so the data are a little more complex. Moreover the "JSON" data contains not quoted names of properties (`id`, `price` ... instead of `"id"`, `"price"`...). Do you really load such data per Ajax from the server or you just use `datatype: "local"` and want to fill the grid using the `data` parameter in the form? Please fix the text of your question.

Comment: @Oleg Sorry, the "root" in "jsonReader" wasn't supposed to be there. I updated the question, my grid options are there now. Can you have a look, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I should mention that there exist large difference between JSON and object initialization. The syntax

```
var data = [
    { "id": 1, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 2 } },
    { "id": 2, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 3 } },
    { "id": 3, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 4 } },
    { "id": 4, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 5 } }
];
```

declare variable `data` and initialize it. The variable `data` have the type `object`. Because the names of all properties `id`, `price` and `data` contains no spaces, dots and other special characters one can rewrite the above code like

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, price: 99.99, data: { dataId: 2 } },
    { id: 2, price: 99.99, data: { dataId: 3 } },
    { id: 3, price: 99.99, data: { dataId: 4 } },
    { id: 4, price: 99.99, data: { dataId: 5 } }
];
```

Another construction

```
var myJsonString = '[ { "id": 1, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 2 } }, { "id": 2, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 3 } }, { "id": 3, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 4 } }, { "id": 4, "price": 99.99, "data": { "dataId": 5 } } ]';
```

declare and initialize the variable `myJsonString` of the type `string` (!!!). One can easy convert the string `myJsonString` to object `data` using [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) or [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or even using [eval](http://www.json.org/js.html) function of JavaScript.

So the string used on the right side of `myJsonString` initialization is JSON string, but not the initializer from the first example.

The code which you posted like `dataType="local"` instead of `datatype: "local"` or `gridView: true` instead of `gridview: true`. If you use `dataType: "local"` for example instead of `datatype: "local"` then the option will be ignored and the default `"xml"` value of `datatype` will be used. It will not what you need.

Nevertheless the question stay: ho to read such data and assign rowid values from `data.dataId`.

Because you use `datatype: "local"` one need use `localReader` instead of `jsonReader`:

```
localReader: { id: "data.dataId" }
```

instead of

```
jsonReader: { id: 'data.data.id' }
```

used in your code.

The corresponding demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/darksoulsong.htm). It displays

[image]

You can easy verify (using Developer Tools of Chrome, Internet Explorer or Firefox) that the rowids of the grid are 2,3,4,5 and not 1,2,3,4:

[image]

Comment: There are some typos in my question, that's why "=" is  used where ":" should be. Thanks for pointing that out.The same goes for "dataType", I'll fix that.
localReader did the trick. Thank you very much!!